# XSL-FO Processor for C/C++

Tags: xsl-fo

Does anyone know about the processor for XSL-FO based on C/C++ for Windows XP and for free? My product is based on c++ and I don't want to use Apache's FOP so that I don't have to bundle JVM with my product. I could find commercial ones but I need a free one. Someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://xmlroff.org/ - it's C and available for free.

Comment: This website is broken as of the date of this comment

Comment: @pwaring: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out. I changed the link back again.

Answer (score 0):

If xmlroof not prove good enough, check this: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html to see how to invoke FOP from C++ (JVM is quite widespread).

Comment: That link is broken now, updated one is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html