# Is there a free C++ xsl-fo to PDF engine?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qt4, xsl-fo

Is there an xsl-fo to PDF engine written in C++ that can be used in QT?

The engines I have come across so far are in java.

Comment: xml is a format for storing data. It has no connection to formatting or reports. You haven't explained enough anyone can answer this question. Stackoverflow is good at getting answers to specific technical questions

Comment: @Jay: XSL-FO is a language for formatting XML data and may be used to genereate PDF documents. This is a valid question and I'd like to know the answer to this one also :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244735/xsl-fo-processor-for-c-c

Answer (score -1):

You should use QXmlQuery: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qxmlquery.html)

From qt docs:

> Running an XSLT stylesheet is like running an XQuery, except that when you construct your QXmlQuery, you must pass QXmlQuery::XSLT20 to tell QXmlQuery to interpret whatever it gets from setQuery() as an XSLT stylesheet instead of as an XQuery. You must also set the input document by calling setFocus().

Code:

```
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.setFocus(QUrl("myInput.xml"));
query.setQuery(QUrl("myStylesheet.xsl"));
query.evaluateTo(out);
```

where "out" is pdf file. and xsl file define how to trasform your xml file to pdf.

Comment: The OP is not asking how to run an XSLT transform. He/She is asking about an XSL-FO processor.